# Флаги компилятора, уменьшение размера .ехе

Tags: gcc, g++

Есть ли какие-нибудь флаги компиляции в MinGW, позволяющие уменьшить объём исполнимого файла-программы? Одна и та же программа, скомпилированная c VS и MinGW, имеют существенно отличающиеся размеры.

Comment: А чем не устраивает компилирование в VS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну отключите отладочную информацию (уберите ключ -g), задайте подходящий уровень оптимизации ключом -O (-O2 -O3 -Os). Потом натравите на exe'шник утилиту strip (удаление символов).